# redirect domain and all sub domain to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want with `htaccess` code redirect domain and sub domain to another domain .
I am using the code below
But it does not work properly

please help me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websoft3\.ir$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.websoft3\.ir$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/websoft3\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```